# SELECT distinct still gives duplicates due to the join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL statement in Access which left joins itself to show 2 lines in de database in 1 line in the report.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Action,
                A.Assignee,
                A.MachineID,
                A.TRDate,
                A.Remarks,
                Iif([B.Action] = "Lock", [B.ActionRemarks], "") AS Locked,
                C.VendorType
FROM   (ExportVendorWeekly AS A
        INNER JOIN Vendors AS C
                ON A.Assignee = C.VendorName)
       LEFT JOIN ExportVendorWeekly AS B
              ON ( A.ID = B.ID )
                 AND ( A.Date = B.Date )
WHERE  ( ( A.Action <> "Lock" )
         AND ( ( A.Assignee = "GTN" )
                OR ( C.VendorType = "MIT" ) ) )
ORDER  BY A.TRDate,
          A.MachineID;
```

The first line in the table contains Action "DoSomething" and the second line in the table contains Action "Lock". These two actions need to be shown in one line in two different columns.
With the SQL statement I have now it still shows two lines, with only in the second line the B.ActionRemarks.

Now I understand this can be done by using the IN clause but I dont know how to apply this. Hope anyone can help.

Comment: this left join `LEFT JOIN ExportVendorWeekly AS B` is not specified enough. I think you should add `AND A.Action > B.Action`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ExportVendorWeekly AS B ON ( A.ID = B.ID ) AND ( A.Date = B.Date ) AND B.Action = 'LOCK'`  notice you need to limit the records in that table to just those that are 'LOCK' action.

Comment: @Sebas ms-access requires parenthesis around joins beyond the first. I hate it too, but it's correct to include them here.

Comment: @Chance Oh crap my bad then... so odd

Comment: Thanks. What I did now is create 3 queries. #1 for to JOIN A and C using the WHERE clause. #2 to create the list I want for all records that have action Lock. And #3 to JOIN Q1 and Q2 based on ID/Date. That works. Would be nice to have this in a single query but I just dont get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Need more info:

1. Is ID (in alias A/B) unique?
2. Is C.VendorName unique?

If not you can expect the LEFT JOIN to yield more than 1 row, especially in case there are 2 rows with **equal ID** and **different Date** fields

Comment: The ID in comination with the Date is unique. The Vendor name is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data, I think you need to change your query structure:

```
SELECT 
    A.Action,
    A.Assignee,
    A.MachineID,
    A.TRDate,
    A.Remarks,
    IIF([B.Action] = "Lock", [B.ActionRemarks], "") AS Locked,
    C.VendorType
FROM
    (SELECT Action, Assignee, MachineID, TRDate, Remarks
     FROM ExportVendorWeekly
     WHERE Action <> "Lock") A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Action, Assignee, MachineID, TRDate, Remarks
     FROM ExportVendorWeekly
     WHERE Action = "Lock") B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
    AND A.Date = B.Date
INNER JOIN Vendors AS C
    ON A.Assignee = C.VendorName
WHERE
    A.Assignee = "GTN" 
    OR C.VendorType = "MIT" 
ORDER BY 
    A.TRDate,
    A.MachineID;
```

This is, assuming you actually only have 2 possible values for Action as you stated in your question.  Otherwise, it's going to create a Cartesian Join.

Comment: Thanks. Seems logical. Tried to use this code but Access gives me an error when trying it: Missing operator in query expression. Cant find where.

Comment: Possibly needs parenthesis for the "OR" statement?  Put the SQL in the query and then change the view to Design View.  Access usually fixes small things like that on its own.